# What exactly does いな mean in Japanese?

Tags: word-requests

I know it seems like いいな means "that's good" but in anime like Akagi and Kaiji, the narrator says いな and the subtitles translate it as "that's wrong". Is いな some kind of old phrase for "that's wrong"? What does it mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

いな is an archaic form of 'no' (sometimes written with kanji as 否). You can still hear it in modern Japanese in a few phrases, like ～か否か ('whether or not ～').

いいな is, of course, いい+な, i.e. 'that's good'.

Comment: There's also the verb [否む【いなむ】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/14272/m0u/%E5%90%A6/) (apparently from the classical [否ぶ【いなぶ】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/14262/m0u/%E5%90%A6/), a verb derived from 否【いな】).

Comment: It is hardly archaic.

Comment: When is 否 on it's own normally used in modern japanese? or is it not normally used?

Comment: @TokyoNagoya - If it's not archaic, it's still certainly unsuited to informal/colloquial speech.

Comment: @Meg We don't say [否]{いな} on its own in real conversation (at least in modern Japanese. I don't know about classic Japanese). I think I've seen it used on its own in essays or novels, like 「～～か？否。」to mean「～～か？いや違う。」

Answer (score 3):

Yes,  like Sjiveru, I wasn't sure if you meant ”良いな”　or "否”. I believe that  "否” is used rather infrequently.  Of course, as Sjiveru mentioned, ”良いな” means, "that's good."  But, of course, it embodies multiple meanings.  It can also mean "That's good for you. And I'm envious." This is often used by women in a sort of whiney (and I mean that with all due respect :) voice that ends with falling intonation. It can also be used at the end of an informal meeting (like a high school club meeting) to close the meeting and confirm that all attendees agree on what's been decided in the meaning. It can also be used sarcastically.